# Zabbix monitoring of OWA authorization

Tags: zabbix, outlook-web-app, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I have Zabbix server 5.0 and I should check an availability of Outlook authorization.
I'm trying to make a Web scenario with 2 steps:

1. Checking of the authorization page.
   I use https://<domain_name>/owa but it is redirected to https://<domain_name>/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2f<domain_name>%2fowa%2f. I tick "Follow redirects" and get status code 200.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzmhp.jpg
2. Trying of authorization.
   I use the same URL that I was redirected to in the first step, also I input this in Raw Post
   destination=https%3A%2F%2F<domain_name>%2Fowa&flags=4&forcedownlevel=0&username=&password=&isUtf8=1 (I can use Form Data too). But if I input an invalid password and username, status code in response is 200 too (screens are below). I think it's because of redirections: authorization is not done and I was redirected at the same page.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVAwa.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ddgp.jpg
   After this step is finished I get status code 200 always.
   How to do it correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Add a string check to the scenario you already created. Look for a string that is present only after a successful login.

> Required regular expression pattern.
> Unless retrieved content (HTML) matches the required pattern the step will fail. If empty, no check on required string is performed.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/web_monitoring

Comment: When I try to find required string I get an error, because my authorization process is not succesfull, I'm redirected to the same page always. I think that I should make a suitable request considering redirections when I try to authorize. I've already tryed to do it like in this example, but because of redirections my case is more difficult.